# Processing data in PHP, iteratively assign variables to every 8 items, to catagorize them to be added to an SQL database

Tags: php, arrays, variables

A PHP array, with items like
Date, number, number, number, number, number, Date, number, number, number, etc...

but all in numbered array as individual items

What I need is to take this array and be able to process a large data set and actually assign the variables so that I can put them into a database like

Date         Number1  Number2  Number3  Number4

01/01/2001.      01.      02.      03.      04

So far, I'm able to open the file, and pull the number into an array but that's about it.

```
<?php 
$lines=array();
$fp=fopen('numbers.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($fp))
{
    $line=fgets($fp);

    //process line ?
    $line=trim($line);

    //add to array
    $lines[]=$line;
}
fclose($fp);
print_r($lines);
?>
```

What do you suggest I do to at least display the items from the array in the desired format. Ideally I'd like to get them into a database so I can run analytics. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello @Autobahn, please specify your question. What exact is your problem? What do you expect to happen? What is happening? See [here for further details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do I cycle through these numbers to assign them to variables? if the array is just numbered but the data is sets of data, like date, number, number then repeats, date, number, number. In order to view/format these to put in to a databse, how do I iterate through the data pulled from the text in order to make the variable assignments and clean up the data?

Comment: Maybe a better question would be how do I take every 8 items from the array and place them into a new array so that once the data is processed, I'm left with one array that contains several arrays, each with 8 items in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the function [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```php
<?php

// create example data
$lines = [];
for($i=1; $i < 32; $i++)
    $lines[] = "Entry $i";


// this is the function you are looking for - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php
$dataSets = array_chunk($lines, 8);

// Lets print our results
// First loop throu all datasets…
foreach($dataSets as $index => $dataSet){

    // "\n" is a new line
    echo ("Data set $index has this entries: \n");

    // … and then throu all entries
    foreach($dataSet as $index => $entry){
        // "\t" is the tab symbol
        echo "\t [$index] = '$entry' \n";
    }

    echo "\n";
}
```

[Working example to play arround](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/82cdb5c7c5e423a7bfa9de0a6033abbd0478fce6)

Comment: Verim, You are a hero. I've been wrestling with array_slice trying to do the same thing to no avail. Thank you very much!